# How to select/highlight text in React Native

Tags: react-native

I am making an English Reading app. When the user clicks on a word, they will see the translation of that word.

So how to make text is selected when the user clicks and holds for some time? I desire something likes `document.onselectchange` event in JavaScript for the web.

Comment: Hey I am trying to implement similar feature, did you found out solution for this

Comment: No, it seems RN does not support. You can make the whole of paragraph selectable, but not only a part.

Answer (score 2):

wrap the Text component with one of the available Touchable components i.e TouchableOpacity. You'll then have access to the onLongPress prop, where you can call a function which allows you to change the background color of the text to give the feel of being selected.

Comment: can it help me select part of the text? cause I would not like to select the whole text

Comment: As far as I am aware, this feature hasn't yet been implemented to React Native, hence the work-around approach in my answer, it seems that there have been other work arounds which maybe better than my own a detailed in the following github thread
 https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/2447

which advises to use a TextInput component with editable: false and then styled to look like a Text component

UPDATE: This has changed since I last looked, appears that you might be able to use <Text selectable>TEXT</Text>

Comment: does press and hold not selecting the word for you?